# How to execute <leader>pcd mapping?

Tags: key-bindings

I want to use https://github.com/stephpy/vim-php-cs-fixer plugin. I have installed both php-cs-fixer in my path and also the plugin itself via Vundle.

Documentation says `Default mapping is <leader>pcd` - and I dont understand how to use it.

Google said that leader is backslash (I havent overridden this in .vimrc). So on my keyboard I directly typed "\pcd". When I type "\" nothing happens, but when I type "p" then vim inserts a piece of text I yanked a minute ago. And this is not what I want to happen..

So what exactly am I supposed to type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to press `\pcd` in rapid succession because Vim waits a bit (default is 1 second) to decide what exactly you are trying to do.

See `:help mapleader`.

Comment: You can also make Vim wait forever for `\pcd`, by setting `notimeout`.  However, this has other (generally unwanted) consequences.  See `:help timeout` and `:help timeoutlen` for increased confusion. ;)